# cambiar valor de un datetimeWidget desde JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

Creo un DateTimeField con Django de la siguiente forma:

```
start_date_edited = forms.DateTimeField(label="Fecha inicio", widget=DateTimeWidget(usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3), required=False)
```

Eso me crea un campo donde introducir una fecha, que funciona correctamente, pero necesito que desde JQuery pueda cambiarle el valor a ese datepicker cuyo id conozco.

He probado con `$("#id_start_edit_date").defaultValue = res[0];`

```
$("#id_start_edit_date").val(res[0]);
```

y varias combinaciones más, el valor de res[0] tiene el siguiente formato: "11/02/2018 13:45:25"

Por si queda dudas de qué quiero es cambiar mediante el DOM con Jqery o Javascript el valor que se muestra en ese input.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a pasar la fecha en formato Año/Mes/Día .val(res[0]); debería funcionar
Puedes hacer split y reordenar las posiciones.

```
var normalDate = res[0].split(' ');
var dateTimeArr= splittedDate[0].split('/');
var dateParts= dateTimeArr[0].split('/');

$("#id_start_edit_date").val(dateParts[2] + "/" + dateParts[1] + "/" + dateParts[0] + " " + dateTimeArr[1]);
```

Comment: El problema no parece ser el formato de la fecha, porque a veces me funciona y muestra y almacena la fecha correctamente, pero otras veces sin motivo aparente, deja de reconocer el campo como un DateTimeField y lo trata como un campo de tipo text, por lo que no se me despliega el selector de fechas. https://image.prntscr.com/image/wraTvatqRr_InSXvC3bRqg.png Mientras que el aspecto debería ser como el siguiente: https://image.prntscr.com/image/EVatzHhxThqn106EAk7wSg.png En el que si te fijas bien, el color de fondo del campo de texto es diferente.